# php and jQuery, copying files and displaying status

Tags: php, jquery, copying

I'd like to ask if this 'synchronizing-scenario' is possible with php and javascript/jQuery...

I have a lots of files with their names in `yyyymmdd.png` format on a server with no ftp access (e.g. `http://www.example.com/20111228.png`). I would like to run a PHP/js script on my LOCAL server which would download all of the files to my local disk following few rules:

i) check if remote file already exists on local disk and if so just skip it
ii) display status on my html page in some kind of list or whatever for each file (e.g. `20111228.png - file exists` or `20111228.png - file doesn't exist`)
iii) when non-existing file has been processed (copied to local disk), display `OK` or `ERROR` status next to that item in generated list.

I'm not asking for complete code here... Especially because I'm sure that someone else already did that. But some guides or any url/google query would be extremely helpful :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server can't just access your hard drive. Maybe there are some java/flash proxies, i know that asus driver download works with java and shows status within it. Another option is to compress these files with zip an then download them, so your browser shows how much is left. And if you are able to pack these files with php then maybe there's a solution for "on the fly" comprssing so you can download these files as you compress them (stream)

Found this: http://www.element-it.com/multiple-file-upload-applet/java-uploader.aspx
Didn't fall into details but it said "JavaPowUpload is File Uploader and File Downloader applet" and it supported multiple file download.
My google query: http://www.google.ee/search?q=download+multiple+files+with+progress+bar&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: OK, I see... But couldn't I just check with php if remote file exists on local drive, one by one, and process each if it doesn't exist? Thanks for links, I will check them in details, but I'd like to avoid java applets if possible...

Comment: If you mean your OWN computer harddrive as an "local drive" then the answer is no. In PHP you can't access users hard drive(yrou own physical disk). That beacuse php runs in server. Java/Flash runs from you computer resources and therefore are able to accees/manipluate your files.

Comment: I understand, but if I forgot to mention that I am running that php script on my local machine :)

Comment: it still wont be access anything outside the webroot of your apache/IIS server

Comment: PS - if your PHP script is running on your machine, it effectively means you are looking to synchronize files from one folder on your local drive to another. In that case, just set up a schedules task or batch file. If you meant that the php script is running on your local machines, but you want to synchronize remote server-local drive, then you're not understanding how PHP works.

Comment: That's worng. I have successfully copied files with PHP outside my webroot. Even on different hard drives. My webroot is whole E: drive and i have copied files from drive D: to drive C: (From My Music to Desktop). Right now i'm at work. I can make longer post afterwards.

Comment: xbonez, my idea was to check for files on remote server, and if file with a same name doesn't exist in some directory on my local computer just copy it with PHP's copy() function... I already did that before but report on page was displayed *after* PHP script was processed... My idea is not to wait to PHP finishes its job to see report, but to 'dynamically' display status for each file with js/jquery/ajax or something like that... For example, on ajax success, append <li> which will display PHP's result of copy() and then move to next file in array... Uh, I hope you understand what I need :)